# jQuery - object and function at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just developing my own mini framework for an application I was working on, and I've been studying the jQuery is coded.

I get the way $(selector).function() works, but how come you can call some functions such as:

$.ajax()

Surely this would been the dollar symbol references both a function and the jquery.fn object at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions are objects in JavaScript so they can have properties.

`$` is the jQuery object, when using `$()` it is used as a constructor (it contains some magic so `new` is not necessary); but it also contains lots of methods (and some non-callable properties such as `$.browser`) available as `$.something`

Comment: Could you give me an example of a function that also has a property then. Say that I could call both function() and function.test?

Comment: @JamesLeckenby: Simple. `var a = function() { console.log("from a"); }; a.test = function() { console.log("from a.test"); }; a(); a.test();`

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/vZvgv/1/

```
var $ = function(str) {
    document.write(str+'<br />');
}

$.ajax = function(str) {
    document.write(str+'<br />');
}

$.answer = 42;

$('dollar');
$.ajax('ajax');
document.write($.answer);
```